# Uncaught Error: Container is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, charts

**I'm trying to generate a gantt chart using Google charts and after coding accordingly with the existing php code, I m getting a blank html. Please help me on this to display the chart successfully.**

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the gantt chart package.
     google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["timeline"]});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
       $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/index1.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false ,
      success: function(data) {
           jsonData = data;
         }
          });

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing : " on the div style

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;></div>
```

The `div` is not defined, so the JS cant find it.

The `getElementById` failed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having `data` **format issue**, ***try this***

```
  /*
   // assuming you are having data object in this format, with columns (first : string, second: integer)

  data = [
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]
  */  

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


  function get_gchart_data(data) {
    var g_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    g_data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    g_data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    g_data.addRows(data);
    return g_data;
  }

  function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "localhost:8080/index1.php",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false ,
        success: function(data) {
          var g_data = get_gchart_data(data);

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(g_data, {width: 500, height: 240});
        }
      })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you are accessing `jsonData` on wrong place.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "localhost:8080/index1.php",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false ,
        success: function(data) {
         jsonData = data;
          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, {width: 500, height: 240});
        }
      })  
    };
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It fixed some of my errors. I am getting GET https://ads.panoramtech.net/loader.js?client=wc

Comment: @ArunKumar not getting what error you are facing, can you paste error

Comment: GET http://ads.panoramtech.net/loader.js?client=wc  this is what i m getting on the console page in google chrome after inspecting the page as i m still getting a blank page

Comment: i fixed that but it gives me an error invalid data table format: 3 or 4 columns